# Multiple Swift MapKit routes in order

Tags: swift, mapkit

I want to add the routes of different checkpoints together. Everytime, the routes are ordered in a random way (when executing print(step.instructions)). But up to the point when print(nextCheckpoint, previousCheckpoint) is executed, they're perfectly ordered. Thus, there seems to be a problem (where the different routes are being shuffled up) when creating the MKDirections Request. For your information: In the end, every route is plotted and complete, just not in the desired order. Here's the code:

```
func showExamRoute(checkpoints: Array<Checkpoints>) {
// 1. Retrieve all checkpoints and add an annotation to them
// 2. Plot Poly-line to the corresponding checkpoints
let numberOfCheckpoints = checkpoints.count - 1
for index in 0...numberOfCheckpoints {
    let checkpoint = checkpoints[index]
    let checkpointLocation2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: checkpoint.latitude, longitude: checkpoint.longitude)
    checkpointsArray.append(checkpointLocation2D)
    let annotation = CustomAnnotationPlace(title: "1", coordinate: checkpointLocation2D, info: "checkpoint")
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
let counterTo = checkpointsArray.count
var nextCheckpoint: CLLocationCoordinate2D!
var previousCheckpoint: CLLocationCoordinate2D!

for counter in 1...counterTo {
    if counter == counterTo {
        nextCheckpoint = checkpointsArray[0]
        previousCheckpoint = checkpointsArray[counter - 1]
    } else {
        nextCheckpoint = checkpointsArray[counter]
        previousCheckpoint = checkpointsArray[counter - 1]
    }
    print(nextCheckpoint, previousCheckpoint)
    let destinationLocation = MKPlacemark(coordinate: nextCheckpoint)
    let startingLocation = MKPlacemark(coordinate: previousCheckpoint)
    let request = MKDirections.Request()
    request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: startingLocation)
    request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationLocation)
    request.transportType = .automobile
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = false
    let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
    directions.calculate { [unowned self] (response, error) in
        guard let response = response else { return }
        let route = response.routes[0]
        self.mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline)
        self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(route.polyline.boundingMapRect, animated: true)
        let steps = route.steps
        for i in 0...steps.count - 1 {
            let step = steps[i]
            print(step.instructions)
            examSteps.append(step)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assume that directions.calculate requests, which are async, that are created in the order 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 will all take the same time to process, and therefore the results will always come back in the order 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  You need to handle the results coming back in any order like 1, 3, 4, 5, 2 - do that by replacing `examSteps.append(step)` with something like `examSteps[i] = step` and then waiting for all the i's to come back